Why was the uncut gem stored in a fish?
In the movie Uncut Gems, Adam Sandler's character receives a package which contains a fish. He cuts the fish open and finds a gem inside.
Why was the gem hidden inside a fish?

Are you asking why the gem was hidden at all (which should be fairly obvious IMO), or why it was specifically hidden inside a fish as opposed to something else?

yeah, why a fish not a simple wooden box

to confuse diamond-snipping dogs (humor)

I imagine this was simply to disguise the package's true nature and prevent it from getting stolen by, for example, an opportunistic mail handler. If the average thief were to open a package and see a "simple wooden box", they would likely open the box to see if it contained anything valuable. If the average thief were to open a package and see a seemingly ordinary fish, however, they would likely assume it's literally just a fish and wouldn't bother checking to see if anything's inside.
Adam Sandler's character, as the intended recipient of the package, is presumably already aware of (or able to guess) its true nature, so when he receives the fish, he knows to cut inside it and retrieve the gem. But the average person wouldn't think to do that if the package were to fall into their hands.

Very interesting choice of the containing item.

Presumably not just worried about thieves, but also law enforcement / international customs.

Note the fish would probably have been shipped together with many normal fish, and then when it got into the country the correct fish was found inside the shipment and sent along to its intended recipient. Shipping one fish would be very suspicious and would almost certainly be caught. Could do this with many different things, but searching through a shipment of fish would be even more effective at deterring officials searching for smuggled goods.

One of the last things international customs will just let you ship is a perishable fish.

Fish and other seafood is shipped all over the world all the time. Unless you're just talking about someone shipping an individual fish, in which case yea they probably wouldn't allow that, or it at least wouldn't be straightforward.
